# RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD error on Cut and Paste from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, com, ms-word, vsto

I've developed an add-in for Microsoft Excel 2007 and 2010 with Visual Studio 2010.

It works fine on all the computers (on Windows XP and Windows 7) where it as been installed, except for one machine with Windows 7 and Office 2010.

The following message is displayed when the add-in attempts to automate Microsoft Word 2010 for creating a new document and copy/paste information from an Excel workbook into it:

*Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0002096B-00000-0000-C000-0000000000046}' failed due to the following error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).*

My programs is looping over the worksheets of an Excel workbook and copy them into a Word document. The error occurs after several loops, when the Excel range is copied to the clipboard with the method Range.CopyPicture, then the RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD error is thrown when I try to access my Word application. I don't use multiple threads.

Someone seems to have the same problem but no answer has been provided yet: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/86abd253-9fb5-46cf-8565-dc2eaa02593b

The user has administrative rights, he tried to repair the MS Office 2010 installation, and to uninstall/install it again but it didn't fix the issue.
After installing Office 2007 on his computer, the add-in works fine with Excel 2007, but still not with Excel 2010.

Have you ever seen this error and would you know how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a Word.Document object, Word.Document is only an interface. Word._Document is the implementation of the Word.Document interface (therefore the type that you will see in debug, and in exceptions).

Knowing that Word.Document is only an interface:

> A RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD error occurs when a thread calls via an interface pointer which is for a proxy object that does not belong to the thread's apartment.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172314

I can't really tell you any more than that without a code sample, but I hope this helps you locate the problem.

Edit:

Actually, looking at the link you posted, I would suggest that you scrape all the data you want to copy / paste into the word document out of any COM objects relating to excel **before** you put it into Word. I know this will mean extra work to achieve the correct formatting / tables, but there are lots of things broken with Office COM (e.g. databinding) and it might be more stable / less hassle in the longer term.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Word applications and Excel applications cannot be run inside the same process. So if you are working with both Excel worksheets and Word documents, you must be working with objects from two processes and therefore two different threads (each process has its own set of threads).

However, if you don't create threads, COM will protect you from using objects inside a wrong apartment. For example, if your code creates an new Word document, your access to this object (which lives in a different process) will be done through an automatically created proxy object. If you access other objects through the Word document proxy, it will create other proxy objects. All this happens without you even noticing it. Out of the blue, I would say that you cannot possibly have done something wrong.

I'd try to find a minimal example that shows this behaviour and post it here. It's quite hard to say where you might have gone wrong without some additional information. But I have to warn you, you might not get a solution for your problem. I have done some pretty serious stuff with Excel and automation, and I found some very serious bugs in Excel that require very hackish workarounds. The fact that these bugs have not been fixed since 2005 leads me to believe that Microsoft does not take much interest in Office Automation. It seems as if you have uncovered one more bug.

Regards,
Stuart

PS: I didn't want to send this as an answer, but apparently I have to earn more reputation points in order to be able to make comments. Whyever.